# file download angularjs and servlets

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, servlets

I have an image stored in a database table, with primary key for a particular number. That image below the database to a folder of the java project by means of a servlet.
So far, so good.

My problem is that I need to download that image to the user and I can not do it.

My steps are as follows:

JSP:

```
$scope.downloadFile = function(){
    var tkAct = $scope.ticketActual.tknum;
    var param = {
            nroTk: tkAct
    };
    var res = $http.post($scope.testHost +"/downloadAttachment",JSON.stringify(param));

    });     

    res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
    });
}
```

SERVLET:

```
@WebServlet("/downloadAttachment")
public class downloadAttachment extends HttpServlet {

// size of byte buffer to send file
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
private final int BYTES_DOWNLOAD=1024;
public static final String FILE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("file.separator");

@Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession sess = request.getSession();

    Controller ctrl = Controller.get();
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
    //int nroTicket=-1;
    //nroTicket = 104;
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("NroTk"));
    System.out.println(request.getAttribute("NroTk"));
    JSONObject joParam = getParametrosJo(request);
    Long lNroTk = (Long) joParam.get("nroTk");
    int nroTicket = lNroTk.intValue();        


    Vector<String> vNamesFile =  ctrl.getFile(nroTicket,sc.getRealPath("/downloads"));
   if(vNamesFile.size()==1){
       String archivo = vNamesFile.get(0);
       File downloadFile = new File(archivo);
       String nombreFile = getNombreFileEnvio(nroTicket,downloadFile.getName());

       // if you want to use a relative path to context root:
       String relativePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/downloads/");
       System.out.println("relativePath = " + relativePath);

       // obtains ServletContext
       ServletContext context = getServletContext();

       String mimeType = context.getMimeType(nombreFile);
       if (mimeType == null) {        
           mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
       }               

       response.setContentType(mimeType);
       response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+nombreFile);

        System.out.println("Obteniendo el Stream...");
        System.out.println("nombre del file es: "+nombreFile);
        InputStream is = sc.getResourceAsStream("/downloads/" + downloadFile.getName());

        int read=0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];

        ServletOutputStream out;  
        out = response.getOutputStream();  
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(relativePath+downloadFile.getName());  
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);  
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);  
        int ch =0; ;  
        while((ch=bin.read())!=-1)  
        {  
            bout.write(ch);  
        }  

        bin.close();  
        fin.close();  
        bout.close();  
        out.close();

   }else{
       byte[] zip = zipFiles(getServletContext().getRealPath("/downloads/"),vNamesFile, 95);
       ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
       response.setContentType("application/zip");
       response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=AdjuntosTicket95" + ".ZIP");

       sos.write(zip);
       sos.flush();
   }

}
```

```
 private JSONObject getParametrosJo(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader joParam = request.getReader();
        String texto="";    
        String str = null;
        while ((str = joParam.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(str);
            //texto+=str;
        }
        texto = buffer.toString();
        System.out.println(texto);
        if(!texto.equalsIgnoreCase("")){            
        JSONObject obj = JSONObject.parse(texto);  
            return obj;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

 private byte[] zipFiles(String path, Vector<String> vNamesFile, int nroTk) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
        byte bytes[] = new byte[2048];

        for (String fileName : vNamesFile) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(getNombreFileEnvio(nroTk,fileName)));

            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = bis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                zos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
        }
        zos.flush();
        baos.flush();
        zos.close();
        baos.close();

        return baos.toByteArray();
}

 private String getNombreFileEnvio(int nroTk, String nombreEnFS){
    String[] aNombreFile = nombreEnFS.split("%");
    String nombreFile = aNombreFile[1];
    return nombreFile;
}
}
```

How do I recover that image from the database to the folder / downloads / and deliver it to the user?

Thank you

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "I can not do it" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: **Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.